# How to increase BI Server Cache Size in OBIEE12c

Tags: oracle, obiee

We are using OBIEE12c (12.2.0.4) for analytical reporting. In order to reduce "Cache Miss", we would like to increase the size of BI Server cache. It would be very helpful if anyone would help us by guiding us the way to increase BI server Cache size.

Answer (score 0):

The following is the workaround the increase the size of BI server cache.

Step 1: Login to the Weblogic enterprise manager
(http://server-ip:9500/em)
Step 2: Click on Target Navigation

Step 3: Click on biinstance under Business Intelligence

Step 4: Click on Performance tab, under Configuration tab.

Step 5: Click on Lock and Edit the Configuration file

Step 6:  Tick "Cache Enable"

Step 7:  Now, change the size of BI server cache and then apply and activate changes.

Visit the link (https://www.learn-it-with-examples.com/datawarehouse-bigdata/bi/obiee/enable-disable-oracle-bi-server-cache.html) for more details.